# Express - Is it possible to influence an object depending on the value of the button from a rendered view?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm a beginner trying to make an e-commerce app as a portfolio project. After a user adds items to the shopping cart, he can click the "shopping cart" and proceed to `/cart` route where he sees the names, quantity and subtotals for items he bought. Then, below, there is a counter with the total sum of the purchase.

Apart from that, I would like to introduce a pair of radio buttons which modify the delivery type. I wish for it to work like this:
When button1 is active (e.g. delivery by post, extra $10), the total gets increased by $10,
when button2 is active, the total gets increased by $20.

In the end, the user proceeds to `/checkout` where he sees the ending bill for his purchase as well as give credentials (like address, name, surname, etc.).

I do not know how to do this. I attach the photo of what I have in mind as well as the code for the `/cart` route and EJS view rendered.

[image]

Here is the code for the view:

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') %>
<h1 class="text-center mb-5">Shopping Cart</h1>
<% if(!session.cart){%>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 text-center">
            <p class="bolded">Your shopping cart is currently empty.</p>
            <a href="/products" class="btn btn-primary">Back to the shop</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% } else { %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10 offset-1 text-start">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3 text-center">TITLE</div>
                    <div class="col-2">PRICE</div>
                    <div class="col-2">AMOUNT</div>
                    <div class="col-2">SUBTOTAL</div>
                </div>
                <% for (let product of products){ %>
                    <div class="row text-start border p-2">
                        <div class="col-3 text-center">
                            <%= product.item.name %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 me-4">$<%= product.item.price %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <%= product.qty %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <% const number=product.item.price * product.qty %>
                                <%= number.toFixed(2) %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="/reduce/<%= product.item._id %>"
                                class="btn btn-sm border btn-secondary bg-gradient">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% } %>

                        <form action="" class="my-3">
                            <div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault"
                                        id="radio1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                        Delivery by post (up to 3 workdays) - $10
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="radio2"
                                        checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                                        Instant delivery (24h) - $20
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                        </form>

            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <p class="text-center h1 mt-5">
                    <% if (totalPrice.toFixed(2)==="-0.00" ){ %>
                        Total: $0
                        <% } else { %>
                            Total: $<%= totalPrice.toFixed(2) %>
                                <% } %>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                <a href="/products" class="btn btn-primary">Back to the shop</a>
                <a href="/checkout" class="btn btn-success">Proceed to checkout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
```

And here is the code for the /cart route:

```
router.get('/cart', (req, res) => {
if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.render('cart', { products: null });
};
const cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
res.render('cart', { products: cart.generateArray(), totalPrice: cart.totalPrice });});
```

This functionality is for the "remove" button which removes one item from the quantity of a product.

```
router.get('/reduce/:id', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;
if (!req.session.cart) {
    req.flash('error', 'Cannot delete any more items!')
    return res.redirect('/products');
};
const cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
cart.reduceByOne(id);
req.session.cart = cart;
if (!req.session.cart.totalQty) {
    req.session.cart = false;
}
res.redirect('/cart');
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name attribute to something like 'extraCost10' and 'extraCost20'. Also access the data trough router.post('/cart'). Then in the post route make an if statement to decide whether to add 10 if(extraCost10){ cost += 10} and the same for the other one. If the radio button is not selected the value should be false. If it is selected it turns up true in req.body.

Comment: That is a great answer. I actually came up with this exact idea 5 minutes after posting this question. Using the post route I assign it to the session via req.body[radio's value] and then proceed. Thank you for taking your time to asnwer my question.

Comment: No problem :) This was actually the first time for me to answer somebody's question. Have fun with express.